# Systemctl view targets names

Tags: linux, systemctl

Is there is any way I can view systemd target's names only.

I know I can use:

```
systemctl --type=target
```

but its giving me other information as well like "load active", I only want name of running targets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think `systemctl` on its own can produce this, but you can ask it for unformatted, undecorated output and filter that:

```
systemctl list-units --type=target --plain --no-legend | cut -f1 -d' '
```